# no library called "cairo" was found in Mac

Tags: python-3.x, django-weasyprint

```
OSError: no library called "cairo" was found
no library called "libcairo-2" was found
cannot load library 'libcairo.so.2': dlopen(libcairo.so.2, 2): image not found
cannot load library 'libcairo.2.dylib': dlopen(libcairo.2.dylib, 2): image not found
cannot load library 'libcairo-2.dll': dlopen(libcairo-2.dll, 2): image not found
```

Error comes when i try to use weasyprint library, I have checked so many solutions but didn't find the clear solution for MacOs(BigSur version 11.6).
I'm using python version 3.7. I have tried to use weasyprint with python 3.9 for which it is working perfectly fine.

```
Python 3.7.9 (v3.7.9:13c94747c7, Aug 15 2020, 01:31:08) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> import weasyprint
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/shashank/Desktop/work/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/weasyprint/__init__.py", line 440, in <module>
    from .css import preprocess_stylesheet  # noqa isort:skip
  File "/Users/shashank/Desktop/work/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/weasyprint/css/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from . import computed_values, media_queries
  File "/Users/shashank/Desktop/work/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/weasyprint/css/computed_values.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .. import text
  File "/Users/shashank/Desktop/work/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/weasyprint/text.py", line 14, in <module>
    import cairocffi as cairo
  File "/Users/shashank/Desktop/work/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cairocffi/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    ('libcairo.so.2', 'libcairo.2.dylib', 'libcairo-2.dll'))
  File "/Users/shashank/Desktop/work/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cairocffi/__init__.py", line 45, in dlopen
    raise OSError(error_message)  # pragma: no cover
OSError: no library called "cairo" was found
no library called "libcairo-2" was found
cannot load library 'libcairo.so.2': dlopen(libcairo.so.2, 2): image not found
cannot load library 'libcairo.2.dylib': dlopen(libcairo.2.dylib, 2): image not found
cannot load library 'libcairo-2.dll': dlopen(libcairo-2.dll, 2): image not found
```

for Python version 3.9

```
(penv) shashank@Shashanks-MacBook-Pro pdf % python3 manage.py shell
Python 3.9.9 (main, Nov 21 2021, 03:16:13) 
[Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> import weasyprint
>>>
```

It would be great help if anyone guide me through this problem. Thanks in Advance

Comment: From what I faced before, I had to downgrade the version of weasyprint to be compatible with the older version of cairo.  So probably in your case, check the version of cairo and supported weasyprint version.